# I am trying to get kmeans to plot 5 clusters, but I'm only get 1 cluster plotted

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis

I found some code on SO which seems to work quite well.

This code, directly below, produces the plot, also below.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import cluster
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()


iris = datasets.load_iris()

kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=5, random_state=42).fit(iris.data[:,0:1])
data = [plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(x=iris.data[:,0], 
                                  y=iris.data[:,1], 
                                  mode='markers',     
                                  marker=dict(color=kmeans.labels_)
                                  )]
plotly.offline.iplot(data)
```

[image]

Now, I make a simple substitution in the code, to point to my own data, like this.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import cluster
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

x = df[['Spend']]
y = df[['Revenue']]

kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=5, random_state=42).fit(x,y)
data = [plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(x=df[['Spend']], 
                                  y=df[['Revenue']], 
                                  mode='markers',     
                                  marker=dict(color=kmeans.labels_))]
plotly.offline.iplot(data)
```

That gives me this plot.

[image]

Here is my data frame.

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
  
# initialize list of lists
data = [[110,'CHASE CENTER',53901,8904,44997,4], [541,'METS STADIUM',57999,4921,53078,1], [538,'DEN BRONCOS',91015,9945,81070,1], [640,'LAMBEAU WI',76214,5773,70441,3], [619,'SAL AIRPORT',93000,8278,84722,5]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Location', 'Location_Description', 'Revenue','Spend','Profit_Or_Loss','cluster_number'])
  
# print dataframe.
df
```

I must be missing something silly, but I don't see what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the dimension:

```
# In the iris dataset
>>> iris.data[:,0].shape
(150,)
# Your data
>>> x.shape
(5, 1)

# You need to flatter your array
x.values.flatten().shape
(5,)
```

For example:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import cluster
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

x = df[['Spend']]
y = df[['Revenue']]

x_flat = x.values.flatten()
y_flat = y.values.flatten()

kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=5, random_state=42).fit(x)
data = [plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(x=x_flat, 
                                  y=y_flat, 
                                  mode='markers',     
                                  marker=dict(color=kmeans.labels_))]
plotly.offline.iplot(data)
```

[image: example]

On the other hand [`cluster.KMeans.fit`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.fit) accepts an array (and not two as you are passing). You're going to have to convert them to something of of shape (n_samples, n_features):

```
X = np.zeros((x_flat.shape[0], 2))
X[:, 0] = x_flat
X[:, 1] = y_flat
# X.shape -> (5, 2)

kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=5, random_state=42).fit(X)
```

Comment: Ah. Now it works. I didn't you that I had to flatten it. Thanks for point that out!!